# Is it possible to specify tray when using shell execute (shell32.dll)

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that's using shell execute (shell32.dll) to "open", "print" or "printto" a document. This works nicely (when running out-of-browser (OOB)). I have been reading the documentation for the API that I have found, but I don't find the documentation comprehensive.

I therefore wonder if anyone has any idea of whether it is possible to specify the tray to print from or not. And if possible, how?

Any help or input is appreciated.

Comment: What program you use for printing? (Adobe Reader or Foxit for example)

Comment: I leave that to Windows to decide. I call the shell execute with the document and the print or printto verb.